# Process large data from MySql using Java

Tags: java, mysql, processbuilder

Which is the best way to process large data from MySql using Java. I searched and but i could not find a best solution.

Please consider the factors -

1. During processing do want to lock the table.
2. Tried `Processbuilder` but it is throwing `"java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory"` most of the times.

Comment: define large data ? define using Java ? JDBC ? ODBC ? local server ? define process ? INSERT ? UPDATE ?

Comment: Can you show us a code snippet?  Are you asking about bulk inserts?  Please flesh your question out a bit with more details.

Comment: @Gray im not surprised with questions like this !

Answer (score 0):

I think JDBC is very standard?  Am I missing something?